# Issues with cmath in 3D plotting using Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d, cmath

I have this simple code which tries to get a 3D plot of the real parts of two complex numbers `E1` and `E2` as functions of `t` and `g`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cmath


eps=0.5


def ReE1(t,g):
    E1=eps+cmath.sqrt(t**2-g**2)
    return E1.real 

def ReE2(t,g):
    E2=eps-cmath.sqrt(t**2-g**2)
    return E2.real 



fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
g = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(t, g)
Z = ReE1(X, Y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='winter', edgecolor='none')
Z = ReE2(X, Y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='summer', edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following error while running with Python 3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t2.py", line 28, in <module>
    Z = ReE1(X, Y)
  File "t2.py", line 11, in ReE1
    E1=eps+cmath.sqrt(t**2-g**2)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can we fix it? Also, can we use the complex functions `E1` and `E2` directly (instead of `ReE1` and `ReE2`) and call the `real` module while plotting?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `sqrt` from `cmath` accepts only scalars, whereas you are trying to use it in a vectorized manner by providing it a 2-d array. One solution is to apply `cmath.sqrt` on each element of `t` and `g` by looping through them as follows:

```
def ReE1(t,g):
    E1 = np.zeros(t.shape, dtype='complex')    
    for i in range(t.shape[0]):
        for j in range(t.shape[1]):
            E1[i][j]=eps+cmath.sqrt(t[i][j]**2-g[i][j]**2)
    return E1.real 

def ReE2(t,g):
    E2 = np.zeros(t.shape, dtype='complex')    
    for i in range(t.shape[0]):
        for j in range(t.shape[1]):
            E2[i][j]=eps-cmath.sqrt(t[i][j]**2-g[i][j]**2)
    return E2.real
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what `t.shape[0]` and `t.shape[1]` are doing? Why there is no `g.shape[0]` or `g.shape[1]`? Thanks.

Comment: @hbaromega [0] gives the number of rows in the 2d matrix and [1] gives the number of columns. `shape` returns 50x50 because you have a mesh grid